# Algorithm to find minimum from list of pairs

Tags: algorithm

**The problem statement:**

Given a list of pairs {A|B}
Find the minimum sum where you must take 'm' values from 'A' and 'n' values from 'B'

- you may not use the same 'pair' for both A and B
- the size of the list will be between 2 and 500 items
- the number of items you take (m & n) can also vary
- the numbers in the pair (A & B) are ranged 0-9.

There of course can be multiple pair combinations that give you the correct minimum.

For example, given:

```
1 - {4,5}
2 - {3,2}
3 - {3,1}
4 - {1,0}
```

and desiring 2 from A, 1 from B
the correct answer is **5**
taking 2A(3), 4A(1) and 3B(1).

Another example is:

```
1 - {5,4}
2 - {2,1}
3 - {6,6}
4 - {2,1}
5 - {5,5}
```

and desiring 2 from A, 2 from B
the correct answer is **12**
taking 1A(5), 5A(5), 2B(1), 4B(1).

I have solved this using a brute force approach, but of course as the list grows larger, and m/n increase, the performance suffers greatly.

How can I improve on this brute force approach?
What is this class of problem called?

*Believe it or not, this is not homework!*

Answer (score 0):

It can be formulated as a [minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). Let the pairs be (a_i, b_i). Create vertices s, t, a, b, u_i and arcs from s to a (capacity m, cost 0), from s to b (capacity n, cost 0), from a to u_i (capacity 1, cost a_i), from b to u_i (capacity 1, cost b_i), from u_i to t (capacity 1, cost 0). Send m + n units of flow as cheaply as possible from s to t. Flow on a->u_i means that a_i is chosen. Flow on b->u_i means that b_i is chosen.

It also can be solved by dynamic programming. Let `Cost[i, j, k]` be the minimum sum for choosing `i` A's and `j` B's from the first `k` pairs. Then we have recurrence relations

```
Cost[0, 0, 0] = 0
Cost[i, j, 0] = infinity
    (for all i, j such that i > 0 or j > 0)
Cost[i, j, k] = min {Cost[i,   j,   k-1],
                     Cost[i-1, j,   k-1] + a_k,
                     Cost[i,   j-1, k-1] + b_k}
    (for all i, j, k such that k > 0).
```

Trace back the minimum arguments to reconstruct the optimal choices.

Comment: Wow, I appreciate that.  I remember that class from 3rd year university (20+ years ago).  Unfortunately, I don't think I have the brains anymore to apply it!